# Find chars in string that are not between double qotes

Tags: java, string

I want to find the occurrences of (a) specific character(s) but this String to search can't be between quotes:

Example:

```
"this is \"my\" example string"
```

If you look for the char 'm', then it should only return the index of 'm' from "example" as the other ' is between double quotes.

Another example:

```
"th\"i\"s \"is\" \"my\" example string"
```

I'm expecting something like:

```
public List<Integer> getOccurrenceStartIndexesThatAreNotBetweenQuotes(String snippet,String stringToFind);
```

One "naive" way would be to:

- get all the start indexes of stringToFind in snippet
- get all the indexes of the quotes in snippet
- Depending of the start index of stringToFind, because you have the positions of the quotes, you can know if you are between quotes or not.

Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT:

What do I want to retrieve? The indexes of the matches.

Few things:

- There can be many quoted content in the string to search in: "th\"i\"s \"is\" \"my\" example string"
- In the string :  "th\"i\"s \"is\" \"my\" example string", "i", "is" and "my" are between quotes.
- It's not limited to letters and digits, we can have ';:()_-=+[]{} etc...

Comment: How about removing everything in the quote along with the quote chars and then search if you only want to find the occurrences?

Comment: One brute force option would be to find indices of all quote pairs, all indices of `m`, and then exclude those indices which would fall inside the quotes.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that's what I tried to explain in my last paragraph.

Comment: It's not clear what you plan to do with the substrings that meet your criteria, but other options to consider are the `java.util.regex` package or the `java.io.StreamTokenizer` class. If you are open to adding an open source library, you also have `org.apache.commons.lang3.text`.

Comment: I just want to find the indexes of the occurrences of the string that are not between double quotes.

Comment: I feel that this is really the job for a parser rather than a regex engine.

Comment: Yes, to make it work with a regex, it will be really complicated in my opinion.

Comment: Can a String have more then two double quotes? If yes, how do you define `not between double quotes`?

Comment: From left to right, it will open then close then open then close etc.. Modulo 2. I will edit the question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution:

**Algorithm**:

1. Find all the "Dead Zone" regions within the String (e.g. regions that are off limits because they are within quotes)
2. Find all the regions where the String contains the search string in question (`hitZones` in the code).
3. Retain only the regions in the `hitZones` that are not contained in any `deadZones`. I will leave this part to you :)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class FindStrings
{
    // Just a simple model class for regions
    static class Pair
    {
        int s = 0;
        int e = 0;

        public Pair (int s, int e)
        {
            this.s = s;
            this.e = e;
        }

        public String toString ()
        {
            return "[" + s + ", " + e + "]";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String search = "other";

        String str = "this is \"my\" example other string. And \"my other\" this is my str in no quotes.";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

        List<Pair> deadZones = new ArrayList<Pair>();
        while (m.find())
        {
            int s = m.start();
            int e = m.end();
            deadZones.add(new Pair(s, e - 1));
        }

        List<Pair> hitZones = new ArrayList<Pair>();
        p = Pattern.compile(search);
        m = p.matcher(str);
        while (m.find())
        {
            int s = m.start();
            int e = m.end();
            hitZones.add(new Pair(s, e - 1));
        }

        System.out.println(deadZones);
        System.out.println(hitZones);
    }
}
```

**Note**: The `s` component of all `Pairs` in the `hitZones`, that are not within `deadZones`, will ultimately be what you want.

Comment: That's a solution that works, but it's definitely not straightforward, seems like my implementation wasn't bad then. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could provide some insight.

Answer (score 0):

As Mamun suggested, you can remove all the quotes and strings between quotes and then search. The following is a regex solution (though I agree with Tim that it's probably not a job for a regex engine).

```
String snippetQuoteRemoved = snippet.replaceAll("(?:\")(\\w+)(?:\")","");
// Now simply search in snippetQuoteRemoved
```

**NOTE**: This will look for `\w+` i.e. (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`). Change it to whatever is suitable for your use case.

**EDIT**

I checked if it'd remove everything and that's not the case. Check [here](http://ideone.com/zrERDj).
Also, for those extra special chars, just change the regex to `(?:")([a-zA-Z0-9_';:()_\-=+\[\]\{\}]+)(?:")`.

Comment: Yes, it'd be better if you update your question and give more examples. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: if you have more than one quoted part, it would remove everything except the part at the beginning and the part at the end.

Comment: Alright fair enough, it works as you said, but now I need to keep the same indexes as before. So simply removing by replacing by "" won't do.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

- get all the start indexes of stringToFind in snippet
- get all the indexes of the quotes in snippet
- Depending of the start index of stringToFind, because you have the positions of the quotes, you can know if you are between quotes or not.

  ```
  public List<Integer> getOccurrenceIndexesNotInQuotes(String snippet,String patternToFind) {

      List<Integer> allIndexes = getStartPositions(snippet,patternToFind);
      List<Integer> allQuoteIndexes = getStartPositions(snippet,"\"");
      TreeSet<Integer> allQuoteIndexesTree = new TreeSet<>(allQuoteIndexes);

      List<Integer> finalIndexes = new ArrayList<>();
      for (Integer index : allIndexes){
          Integer quoteIndexValue = allQuoteIndexesTree.floor(index);
          int quoteIndex = allQuoteIndexes.indexOf(quoteIndexValue);
          if (quoteIndexValue == null || !isBetweenQuote(quoteIndex)){
              finalIndexes.add(index);
          }
      }

      return finalIndexes;
  }

  private List<Integer> getStartPositions(String stringToProcess, String regex) {
      List<Integer> out = new ArrayList<>();

      Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(stringToProcess);
      while(matcher.find()) {
          out.add(matcher.start());
      }

      return out;
  }

  private boolean isBetweenQuote(Integer indexInQuoteList){
      return indexInQuoteList % 2 != 1;
  }
  ```